# Google APIs not working, Google Maps not displaying in Android app, and Authentication Failure with Google Sign-In, Only When Converting to APK

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, google-api

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I am encountering an issue with my Android app where the Google APIs are not working as expected, and Google Maps is not displaying properly. I have already tried to troubleshoot the issue and would appreciate any guidance or insights from the community.

I tried to modify the proguard rules but nothing really happened

[image: Proguard]

I also set it to false
[image: Minify]

This is the map looks like when I tried running the app
[image]